# android rest servicehelper singleton

Tags: android, rest, service

Can anyone explain to me, why the ServiceHelper in the first of the design patterns in [Virgils presentation at Google I/O](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) should be a singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [this position](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=xHXn3Kg2IQE#t=1782s) of the video for the next 30 seconds or so, Virgil gives an example-functionality for the helper that gives the answer, I think.

> You can implement a map, from the request id to this intent. And you
>   could always first of all ask the services: Is this particular request
>   id still pending? ...

There should only be one place that holds those information, so you shouldn't be able to create more than one instance of this helper.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is to share the service acrross activities. If one day you have tried to share "complex" data between actvities without persisting data in a DB. You proabvly have used a singelton.

Comment: I know what a singleton is for, but I was wondering what the function is in that specific designpattern. What I have found Out in the meantime since I posted this question is that it probably is  used for posting back results to the activities that activates the service. With a singleton you have one point of access to the service.